# Applying filters on SVG straight lines make line disappear - discussing workaround for flood color filters

Tags: css, html, svg, console.log, svg-filters

I suspect this may relate as [SVG Mask makes line disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475396/svg-mask-makes-line-disappear)
but the above question is about masking, this one about filters, and the  documentation in the above-given answer is removed - https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking

I have a straight path:

```
<path stroke="red" stroke-width="40" fill="transparent" d="M400 -2800 H400 V-4400" filter=""></path>
```

And I am applying a filter defined like this:

```
  <filter id="f1">
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic"
        type="matrix"
        values="0 0 0 0 0
                1 1 1 1 0
                0 0 0 0 0
                0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
```

The line will disappear.

I think it is due because `objectBoundingBox` won't be able to compute the width of a straight vertical line.

The effect I would like to obtain is to change the color of the lines on hover.

I know it could be done in CSS, but I would like to consider the possibility to be more flexible in applying effects.

How could I "flood" the color of the line/paths, and therefore the stroke of the computed geometry for the element, using filters?

In terms of performance, could you also suggest how could I use the browser console to check the impact of filters on rendering VS simply using CSS classes?

Comment: I see no other solution than using css. As from the other post mentioned by you "Keyword objectBoundingBox should not be used when the geometry of the applicable element has no width or no height".

Comment: Use userSpaceOnUse units